# Azure AD B2C custom native login screen for iOS

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How can I implement a native custom login (and register) screen that connects towards a [Microsoft Azure AD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/)﻿?

This is the setup:

- I have a mobile application developed in Xcode/Swift that...
- ...needs to register and login (new) users agains an Azure Active Directory B2C (notice the B2C here, as there are also other AD solutions by Microsoft)

[image]

The solution that Microsoft offers can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal. But this opens a safari window which is not the user experience I am looking for:

[image]

Instead I want to build a native login screen (UIViewController) with my own layout and design, but still want to use the Azure Active Directory B2C.

How could this be done?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you find a workable solution / sample for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We used webview....

Comment: Has someone actually managed to fully embed a login flow from Azure AD B2C natively? If yes, how?

Comment: I did not succeed.p, I am also very interested to know of somebody managed it!

Comment: @HixField, did Apple approved this flow, specially with Apple ID login?

Comment: No we had to add apple sign in

Comment: Is there any update to this? Has anyone else found a solution around this?

Answer (score 4):

For sign-in, you can implement a native page that integrates with [a resource owner password credentials policy in the Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc), which will enable a user's credentials to be `POST`ed to the Azure AD B2C tenant for validation:

```
POST /tfp/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_ROPC_Auth/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: yourtenant.b2clogin.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password&
username=leadiocl%40trashmail.ws&
password=Passxword1&
scope=openid+bef22d56-552f-4a5b-b90a-1988a7d634ce+offline_access
client_id=bef22d56-552f-4a5b-b90a-1988a7d634ce&
response_type=token+id_token
```

For sign-up, a client credential is required to request an access token for [the Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to [create an Azure AD B2C user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#create-a-user-local-or-social-account--), so if you are wanting to implement a native page then you will have to consider also implementing a backend/proxy API that protects the client credential.

Comment: Is ROPC is safe?